# Java: Insert a String at a dynamic index position where the index is a formatted string

Tags: java

I have the string format like this :

```
{a},{b2},{str},{5}...

{a} - index[0], {b2} - index[1],(str} - index[2],{5} - index[3] ...
```

this could be more than 20K or 25K indexes. Even it goes up to 1L.

I want to insert the string "{c3}" at any position, its a dynamic (for ex 3rd) 
the result should be like this

```
{a},{b2},{str},{c3},{5}
```

It's a very frequent operation, not using in console application. It's for a web oriented application. So which is the better way to handle this in java?

Using split method we have to use System.arraycopy to handle it. For the performance side it's a little bit difficult.

So pls suggest me how to handle this is in REGEX. Also guide me whether it is the good way to handle it or tell me if there is a better way?

---

Thanks for ur quick reply.

Yes this is one of the way to solve my problem.

I will explain my problem clearly.

I read the file content from the filestore and finally get the content like this:{a},{b2},{str},{5}...

In that string i have to insert some content at particular index(index is based on {}), after that  have to stored it into filestore.

Read and writing is not problem in my case.we will handle it.

Inserting the particluar index is only problem. whether the server is serve well or not when it is going to hit frequently

Some more doubts:

Suppose the string is having more than 25K indexes, in that case the while loop is execute 25k times.

Insert is the frequent operation,it can be hit morethan 50 times in a minute.(50*25=1250K)

Suppose 25users comes into the same server in that case whether it can be serve well?

I dont know which way is better. Whether your model is suitable for my case?

Please advise me...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that regex is actually slower than parsing explicitly for what you need. The expression required might be a bit complex too. Here's an alternative to consider that doesn't require a large array:

```
String input = "{a},{b2},{str},{5}";
int insertPos = 3;
String insertText = "{c3}";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int pos = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(",");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String next = scanner.next();
    if (pos++ == insertPos) {
        sb.append(insertText);
        sb.append(',');
    }
    sb.append(next);
    sb.append(',');
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // remove the last comma
String output = sb.toString(); // output will be "{a},{b2},{str},{c3},{5}"
```

I'm not sure what your use case is, however you can adapt this to handle more inserts as necessary.

**Edit:** Here's a version that's 50 times faster. Given strings with 50K indexes each it can process roughly 100K input strings per minute in a single thread on typical hardware (so 5 billion indexes/minute).

```
String input = "{a},{b2},{str},{5}";
int insertPos = 3;
String insertText = "{c3}";

String output = input + ","; // add temporary comma
int index = 0;
int pos = 0;
while (index > -1) {
    if (pos == insertPos) {
        output = output.substring(0, index)
                + (pos == 0 ? insertText + "," : "," + insertText)
                + output.substring(index);
    }
    index = output.indexOf(',', index + 1);
    pos++;
}
output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 1); // remove last comma
System.out.println(output); // output will be "{a},{b2},{str},{c3},{5}"
```

Comment: Thx for ur prompt reply. i have posted some more doubts. Can u clarify?

Comment: Updated with a version that 50 times faster :)