# How to check if a string containing 'tags' seperated by any none-word token contains a given tag in Java

Tags: java, regex, tags, java.util.scanner

Does someone know a way on how to check, in Java, if a string containing tags seperated by space, comma or semicolon (or any non-word character) contains a given tag?

For example:

Sample tag string: `tag tag_,tag_2;_tag test_3`

Check for `tag` should return true.
Check for `test` should return false because it the tag string contains `test_3` not `test`.
Check for `hello` should return false.

Also case shouldn't matter but there i could just `upper` the tag string.  The tags may contain only character, digit or underscore.

I was trying to use some regex pattern but, even with the help of many post on stackoverlow, i cannot get i to work as i want it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of possible approaches here.  One way is to split the String using a regular expression that matches on whitespace, commas or tabs then compare the split tokens...

```
String[] tags = stringFullOfTags.split("[\\s,;]+");
```

The regular expression [\s,;]+ will match one or more spaces (\s - note the double escaping of the regular expression special character \s), semicolons or commas.  The String split method will return the array of tokens (in this case tags) separated by values split by tokens matching the regular expression.  The tags array should therefore contain all the tag* elements.

Now to check for certain tag elements convert the array to a List and use the List interfaces convenience methods...

```
List<String> listOfTags = Arrays.asList(tags);
if (listOfTags.contains("tag") {
    ....
} else if (listOfTags.containsAll(Arrays.asList({"tag", "test_3"})) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just use a `Scanner` in this case and declare the delimiters. It'd look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sample = "tag tag_,tag_2;_tag test_3";
    System.out.println("tag = " + containsTag(sample, "tag"));
    System.out.println("test = " + containsTag(sample, "test"));
    System.out.println("hello = " + containsTag(sample, "hello"));
}

public static boolean containsTag(String text, String tag) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter(" |,|;");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If your requirement is that tags can be delimited by anything other than characters, digits and underscores you could just use `"[^A-Za-z0-9_]"` as the delimiter instead of `" |,|;"`.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose not to use regex? At first glance this looks significantly less efficient.

Comment: With regex it can be tricky to cover all cases properly and it's generally more complicated to read. Plus regex is actually not as efficient as you might think. If you review the code that it goes through, it has to compile a pattern, perform matching and creates a lot of objects in the process. Note that `Scanner` is actually using regex for the delimiting. So this is not necessarily as efficient as it could be, although I imagine it doesn't matter unless the OP is dealing with a ton of these.

Comment: Here's an example of going from a `Scanner` that's using regex delimiting to specific code that's 50 times faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468396/java-insert-a-string-at-a-dynamic-index-position-where-the-index-is-a-formatted/5468636#5468636

Comment: The Scanner class is basically using the delimiter as a regex internally. I think this solution reads well. I wouldn't worry about efficiency until you profiled it and found a problem.

Comment: Fair enough, i will make a note for future reference. I suppose it all makes sense. I just find regexes readable and darn fun though XD, so i generally tend to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I think just adding word boundaries `\b` around your tag, that you want to search. This assures, that there is no word character before or after your tag.

```
Pattern.compile("\\b"+tag+"\\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex and a little bit of cheating - but it keeps the regexp easy:

```
String test = "tag tag_,tag_2;_tag test_3";
String tag  = "tag";
String delim = " ,;";    // those are your valid delimiter chars


Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[" + delim + "]" + tag + "[" + delim + "]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" " + test.toLowerCase() + " ");
System.out.println(m.find());
```

(I just added a space at the beginning and at the end ;) )

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but it does not take several things into account, see below for explanation and improvement:

```
 String s = "tag tag_,tag_2;_tag test_3";

 String val = "tag";     
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile(val+"\\W").matcher(s);
 System.out.println(m.find());

 val = "test";
 m = Pattern.compile(val+"\\W").matcher(s);
 System.out.println(m.find());

 val = "hello";
 m = Pattern.compile(val+"\\W").matcher(s);
 System.out.println(m.find());
```

My output is:

```
true
false
false
```

**NOTE**: if you want values like "_tag;" to return false, you have to add the "\W" to the beginning of the pattern too, this can cause an issue though with matching for the start of the line, so you need to use the special `|` and `^` chars like so, and for that matter you may also want to the same thing to the line ending too, using `|` and `$`:
`Pattern.compile("(^|\\W)"+val+"(\\W|$)").matcher(s)`

- `(^|\\W)` = match the line beginning,
  **OR** a non-word character
- `val` = the
  word to match
- `(\\W|$)` = match a
  non-word character **OR** the end of the
  line itself

That will match words in the middle or start or end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

Here's a junit test with some of the solutions for other's:
I think i go for hasTag2 method but it doesn't seem to matter much..

```
public class TagTest extends TestCase {
private TagContainer tc = new TagContainer("tag tag_,tag_2;_tag test_3");

public void testHasTag() {
    test(true, "tag", "tag_", "tag_2", "_tag", "test_3", "TAG", "TEST_3", "TAG_");
    test(false, "test", "_ta", "hello");
}

private void test(boolean result, String... tags) {
    for (String tag : tags) {
        assertEquals(result, tc.hasTag1(tag));
        assertEquals(result, tc.hasTag2(tag));
        assertEquals(result, tc.hasTag3(tag));
        assertEquals(result, tc.hasTag4(tag));
    }
}

class TagContainer {
    private String tagData;

    public TagContainer(String t) {
        this.tagData = t;
    }

    public boolean hasTag1(String tag) {
        String delimeters = " ,;"; // Valid delimiter chars
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[" + delimeters + "]" + tag.toLowerCase() + "[" + delimeters + "]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(" " + tagData.toLowerCase() + " ");
        return m.find();
    }

    public boolean hasTag2(String tag) {
        String[] tags = tagData.toLowerCase().split("[\\s,;]+");
        List<String> listOfTags = Arrays.asList(tags);
        return listOfTags.contains(tag.toLowerCase());
    }

    public boolean hasTag3(String tag) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(tagData.toLowerCase()).useDelimiter(" |,|;");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.next().equals(tag.toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasTag4(String tag) {
        String[] tests = tagData.toLowerCase().split(" |,|;");
        Set<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();
        Collections.addAll(tags, tests);
        return tags.contains(tag.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

}
Thanks!